# How to concate values in messagebox text using C++ win32 API?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, dialog

i want to show the messsagebox using win32 API...

`int pwdexpirydays=5;
MessageBox(hdlg,(LPCSTR)("Your password will expire in %d days",&pwdexpirydays),(LPCSTR)"Logon Message",MB_OK | MB_ICONINFORMATION);`

But i cant get the value...

How to i concate the `pwdexpirydays` values into  `"Your password will expire in %d days"` this string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `snprintf` or std::string for concatenating.

Comment: @ Drakosha : `sprintf (msg,"Your password will expire in %d days.", pwdexpirydays);        strcat (msg,"Do you want to change it now?");        MessageBox(hDlg, TEXT(msg),TEXT("Logon Message"), MB_OKCANCEL| MB_ICONWARNING)` this is code...when i run this GIVE ERROR LIKE THIS... **Lmsg undeclared identifier**... **TEXT(msg)** is the problem...what to do?

Comment: @SanjuMonu - TEXT() is only to be used on static stings, not variables - and all it does is add an L prefix in UNICODE builds - eg. TEXT("foo") turns into L"foo". If you are compiling as unicode, then use _snwprintf instead of the ANSI sprintf.

Comment: @ Drakosha : Ya,i got it.using `(LPCWSTR)msg` gives the string value correctly...thank u for ur help.

Answer (score 3):

If you are doing it a lot you might want to consider a function to make it quick and easy.

```
int MsgBoxPrint(HWND hWnd, int Type, char *Caption, char *Format, ...)
{
    va_list ArgList;
    char Temp[4096];

    va_start(ArgList, Format);
    vsnprintf(Temp, 4096, Format, ArgList); 
    va_end(ArgList);

    return MessageBox(hWnd, Temp, Caption, Type);
}
```

Then you would call it like so:

```
MsgBoxPrint(hdlg, MB_OK | MB_ICONINFORMATION, "Logon Message", \
     "Your password will expire in %d days", pwdexpirydays);
```